# How could i optimize my codeigniter application?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

Is there any way to optimize the codeigniter application? I need to optimize as per coding standards as well as loading purpose. My Webpage takes 6 to 8 sec to load the complete page. but i need it to load in between 2 to 4 sec, So how many ways to compress the code and make faster execution of the page.

Comment: First off, even if some kind hearted soul decided to optimize your code, the code would need to be in your question, right now you there's nothing to help you with.

Comment: Unclear and useless question, but there is a [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs) for code igniter where they speak about caching. And there is [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to run php code faster (caching OP code).

Comment: You can use CDN to serve your static content (css,images,js). Also add cloudflare which will boost your content load time. Lazy load your images through jquery and cache your pages to avoid database calls. Here is a caching library which is easy to configure and use http://www.phpfastcache.com/. Enable gzip compression in .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the benchmarking class to see where your code has to be improved.
see the docs: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you're writing down your code at that time you don't have a idea about optimization, but some application is too large to handle it so, as per optimization purpose and code optimization purpose you have think about that.

I have set enable_hooks = TRUE in the config file, also use .htaccess (gzip) compression code to compress your application.

Is it available any other way to compress your code (specially in codeigniter)?